# Iterate through an Object of Arrays

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

Given an object of arrays and i have to iterate through every each value of every array in this object [image]

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(UPDATE)** (thanks @pilchard)

Try this (replace obj with your own object):

```
Object.values(obj).forEach((array) => {
  array.forEach((value) => {
    console.log(value);
    // Code for each value of each array
  });
});
```

Comment: no need for spread, `Object.values()` returns an array